# Excel, how to exclude one row from a look up range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to do a simple task. On column A I have some values, numbers, on column b I want to check if the value on column B is univocal on al column A. I tried to do this with an if and a Look Up, but if I put the whole column A as a range i'm considering the row on which I'm doing the check, but obviously I want to exclude this value from the look up, how can I do it? Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"Not OK","OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple task, here is a simple cheat (if you are using one of the following versions of Excel):

[image: Versions]

[image: CF]

Highlight the data you want to check for duplication, click the **Conditional Formatting** button under `Home` tab, go to the last option **Duplicate Values...**, you can customise the format for duplicated values or simply leave it as default, and click <kbd>OK</kbd>, there you go :)